# CUDA shared memory writes incur unexplainable long latency

Tags: cuda, gpu-shared-memory

This has been driving me crazy. I have a 3D grid of 1D blocks. Each block contains 272 threads. Each thread does a dot product of two vectors and stores its result in a corresponding location in `__shared__` memory array of doubles sized at `[272]` which is the same number of threads. the main thread is calling multiple kernels and I am adding up time taken to execute them all. When I comment out the line that writes to shared memory, I get execution times around 2,401 ms. When I comment out the shared memory write line, I get tremendously long times like 450,309 ms. I tried using `int` values instead of `double`s. I also tried having a `if(threadIdx.x ==0)` statement to let just one thread do its write, to avoid possible bank conflicts. Nothing seems to work.

Here is the calling thread code:

```
double theta=0;
int count=0;
cudaEventRecord(start,0);
while(theta <180)
{
    theta+=0.18;

    calc_LF<<<gridDim, blockDim>>>(ori_dev, X_dev, Y_dev, Z_dev, F_dev, F_grad_dev, g_oriD, r_vD, LF);
    calc_S<<<gridDim, 272>>>(g_traD, LF, Ci, C);
    count++;
}
cudaEventRecord( stop, 0 );
cudaEventSynchronize( stop );
cudaEventElapsedTime( &elapsedTime, start, stop );
err = cudaGetLastError();
if ( cudaSuccess != err )
{
    fprintf( stderr, "Cuda error in file '%s' in line %i : %s.\n",
             __FILE__, __LINE__, cudaGetErrorString( err) );
}
else
{
    fprintf( stderr, "\n \n Cuda NO error in file '%s' in line %i : %s.\n",
             __FILE__, __LINE__, cudaGetErrorString( err) );
    printf("\n %d orientation updates: Total Time = %3.10f ms\n", count, elapsedTime);
}
```

The Kernel in question is the `calc_S` kernel, whose code is:

```
__global__ void calc_S(double* g_traD, double* LF, double* Ci, double* C)
{
    __shared__ double G[H];
    int myTRA[W];
    int tx= threadIdx.x;

    for(int j=0; j<W; j++)
    {
        myTRA[j]= getElement(g_traD, tx, j, W);
    }
    double sum;
    for(int j=0; j<W; j++)
    {
        sum += myTRA[j] * LF[j];
    }       

    // Write your sum to shared memory
    G[threadIdx.x]=sum;
    // __syncthreads();
}
```

I am using MS Visual Studio 2008 with CUDA 4.2 and a GPU of compute capability 2.0 (namely a GeForce GTX 580).
Notes:

- 272 threads per block.
- H/W threading limit: 1,536 / 272 = up to 5 blocks
- Shared memory limit: G[272] of doubles = 2,176 bytes needed. 48K / 2176=  up to 22 blocks (which will never happen but we know shared memory is no limitation)
- registers are not an issue at all.

So, it should be that 5 blocks can be executing at the same time.

Thanks for any help.

Mai

##### Edit:

Here is a shortened version of the entire code. The whole code can be run in the [`MatrixMul` Nvidia SDK example](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples/tree/master/Samples/0_Introduction/matrixMul).

In File `MatrixMul.cu`

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // reading data from Matlab into double arrays
    //CUDA begins here:
    if(shrCheckCmdLineFlag(argc, (const char**)argv, "device"))
    {
        cutilDeviceInit(argc, argv);
    }
    else
    {
        cutilSafeCall( cudaSetDevice(cutGetMaxGflopsDeviceId()) );
    }
    int devID;
    cudaDeviceProp props;

    // get GPU props
    cutilSafeCall(cudaGetDevice(&devID));
    cutilSafeCall(cudaGetDeviceProperties(&props, devID));

    printf("Device %d: \"%s\" with Compute %d.%d capability\n", devID, props.name, props.major, props.minor);
    
    //Declare Device memory for matrices read from Matlab
    double *X_dev;    // size 19 x 1
    double *Y_dev;    // size 19 x 1
    double *Z_dev;    // size 17 x 1
    double *r_vD;     // size 544 x 3
    double *g_oriD;   // size 544 x 3
    double *g_traD;   // size 272 x 544
    double *cov_D;    // size 272 x 272
    double *cov_i_D;  // size 272 x 272
  
    err= cudaMalloc((void**)&X_dev, sizeX*sizeof(double));
    errorCheck(err);

    err= cudaMalloc((void**)&Y_dev, sizeY*sizeof(double));
    errorCheck(err);

    err= cudaMalloc((void**)&Z_dev, sizeZ*sizeof(double));
    errorCheck(err);

    err= cudaMalloc((void**)&r_vD, sizeR_V*sizeof(double));
    errorCheck(err);

    err= cudaMalloc((void**)&g_oriD, sizeG_ori*sizeof(double));
    errorCheck(err);

    err= cudaMalloc((void**)&g_traD, sizeG_tra*sizeof(double));
    errorCheck(err);

    err= cudaMalloc((void**)&cov_D, sizeCov*sizeof(double));
    errorCheck(err); 

    err= cudaMalloc((void**)&cov_i_D, sizeCov_i*sizeof(double));
    errorCheck(err); 

    //Transfer Xs, Ys, and Zs to GPU Global memory
    cudaMemcpy(X_dev,dipole_x_coords, sizeX*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    errorCheck(err);

    cudaMemcpy(Y_dev,dipole_y_coords, sizeY*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    errorCheck(err);

    cudaMemcpy(Z_dev,dipole_z_coords, sizeZ*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    errorCheck(err);

    // Transfer r_v, g_ori, and g_tra to GPU memory
    cudaMemcpy(r_vD, r_v, sizeR_V*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    errorCheck(err);

    cudaMemcpy(g_oriD,g_ori, sizeG_ori*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    errorCheck(err);

    cudaMemcpy(g_traD,g_tra, sizeG_tra*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    errorCheck(err);

    // Transfer cov, and cov_i to GPU memory
    cudaMemcpy(cov_D, cov_post, sizeCov*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    errorCheck(err);

    cudaMemcpy(cov_i_D,cov_post_i, sizeCov_i*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    //Specify dimensions of block and grid
    dim3 gridDim(sizeX, sizeY, sizeZ);   // 19 x 19 x 17
    int numThreads=(int) sizeR_V/3;      // numThreads = 544
    dim3 blockDim(numThreads,1,1);       // 544 x 1 x 1 

    //call Cuda wrapper
    float cf = runB(X_dev, Y_dev, Z_dev, r_vD, g_oriD, g_traD, cov_i_D, cov_D, blockDim, gridDim, sizeG_tra, tra_W, tra_H);

    int c=0;
    scanf("%d", c);
    return 0;
}

float runB(double* X_dev, double* Y_dev, double* Z_dev, 
           double* r_vD, double* g_oriD, double* g_traD, double* Ci, double* C,
           dim3 blockDim, dim3 gridDim, int sizeG_tra, int tra_W, int tra_H)
{  
    cudaError err;

    // Calculate the size of thread output in global memory
    size_t size_F = gridDim.x * gridDim.y * gridDim.z * blockDim.x;
    size_t size_F_grad = gridDim.x * gridDim.y * gridDim.z * blockDim.x * 3;

    // Make global memory space for F and F_grad 
    double* F_dev;
    double* F_grad_dev;
    err= cudaMalloc((void**)&F_dev, size_F*sizeof(double));
    errorCheck(err); 
    err= cudaMalloc((void**)&F_grad_dev, size_F_grad*sizeof(double));
    errorCheck(err); 

    //Allocate Device memory for LF 
    double *LF;
    err= cudaMalloc((void**)&LF, 544*sizeof(double));
    errorCheck(err); 

    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    float elapsedTime;

    cudaEventCreate(&start);
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);

    double theta=0;
    cudaEventRecord(start,0);
    while(theta <180)
    {
        theta+=0.18;
        calc_LF<<<gridDim, blockDim>>>(ori_dev, X_dev, Y_dev, Z_dev, F_dev, F_grad_dev, g_oriD, r_vD, LF);
        calc_S<<<gridDim, 272>>>(g_traD, LF, Ci, C);
        count++;
    }
    cudaEventRecord( stop, 0 );
    cudaEventSynchronize( stop );
    cudaEventElapsedTime( &elapsedTime, start, stop );
    err = cudaGetLastError();
    if ( cudaSuccess != err )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Cuda error in file '%s' in line %i : %s.\n",
                 __FILE__, __LINE__, cudaGetErrorString( err) );
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "\n \n Cuda NO error in file '%s' in line %i : %s.\n",
                 __FILE__, __LINE__, cudaGetErrorString( err) );
        printf("\n 180 orientation updates: Total Time = %3.10f ms\n",elapsedTime);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In file `MatrixMul_kernel.cu`:

```
#define HDM_DIM 3 
__global__ void calc_LF(double* ori_dev, double* X_dev, double* Y_dev, double* Z_dev, double* F_dev, double* F_grad_dev, 
                        double* g_oriD, double* r_vD, double* LF)
{ 
    // Get this block's global index 
    int blockId= blockIdx.x + gridDim.x*blockIdx.y + gridDim.x*gridDim.y*blockIdx.z;
    int tx= threadIdx.x;
    // This thread's global index
    int gtx= blockId*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    double r_v[3];
    double g_ori[3];
        
    // Each thread reads 1 row (3 values) of r_vD 
    r_v[0] = getElement(r_vD, tx, 0, HDM_DIM);
    r_v[1] = getElement(r_vD, tx, 1, HDM_DIM);
    r_v[2] = getElement(r_vD, tx, 2, HDM_DIM);
    // Each thread reads 1 row (3 values) of g_oriD (which contains grad.ori data)
    g_ori[0] = getElement(g_oriD, tx, 0, HDM_DIM);
    g_ori[1] = getElement(g_oriD, tx, 1, HDM_DIM);
    g_ori[2] = getElement(g_oriD, tx, 2, HDM_DIM);
    
    //fetch d_ori from global memory
    double d_ori[3];
    for(int i=0; i< 3; i++){
        d_ori[i]= ori_dev[3*gtx+i];
    }   
    //read this block's X, Y, Z location
    double x= X_dev[blockIdx.x];
    double y= Y_dev[blockIdx.y];
    double z= Z_dev[blockIdx.z];     
     
    double c2[HDM_DIM];
    c2[0]= d_ori[1]*z - d_ori[2]*y;
    c2[1]= d_ori[2]*x - d_ori[0]*z;
    c2[2]= d_ori[0]*y - d_ori[1]*x;
    
    // Fetch F and F_grad from global memory
    double F = F_dev[gtx];
    double F_grad[3];
    for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
    {
        F_grad[j] = F_grad_dev[gtx*3+j];
    }

    double c1[HDM_DIM];
    c1[0]= F* c2[0];
    c1[1]= F* c2[1];
    c1[2]= F* c2[2];
    
    double d3= c2[0]*r_v[0] + c2[1]*r_v[1] + c2[2]*r_v[2];
    
    double s2[HDM_DIM];
    for(int j=0; j<HDM_DIM; j++)
    {
        s2[j] = d3*F_grad[j];
    }
    
    double s1[HDM_DIM];
    for(int j=0; j<HDM_DIM; j++)
    {
        s1[j] = c1[j] - s2[j];
    }
    
    double b_v[HDM_DIM];
    for(int j=0; j<HDM_DIM; j++)
    {
        b_v[j] = (10^-7)/(F*F) * s1[j]; 
    }

    double sum=0;
    for(int j=0; j<HDM_DIM; j++)
    {
        sum += b_v[j]*g_ori[j];
    }   

    // Write this thread's value to global memory
    LF[tx]= sum;
 
}
```

Worth mentioning is that this `calc_LF` kernel used to write its final result in shared memory which increased execution time from about 500+ ms to about 2,500 ms (i.e. just the shared memory write line roughly multiplied the time by 5).

```
__global__ void calc_S(double* g_traD, double* LF, double* Ci, double* C)
{
    __shared__ double T[H];
    __shared__ double G[H];

    // Get this block's global index 
    int blockId= blockIdx.x + gridDim.x*blockIdx.y + gridDim.x*gridDim.y*blockIdx.z;
    int tx= threadIdx.x;
    // This thread's global index
    int gtx= blockId*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    
    int myTRA[W];
    double my_LF[W];
    for (int i=0; i<W; i++){
        my_LF[i]= LF[gtx];
    }

    for(int j=0; j<W; j++){
        myTRA[j]= getElement(g_traD, tx, j, W);
    }
    double sum;
    for(int j=0; j<W; j++)
    {
        sum += myTRA[j] * my_LF[j];
    }       

    // Write your sum to shared memory
    G[tx]=sum;
    __syncthreads();
}
```

Comment: When you comment out a line and get a big change like that, it probably means that the compiler is optimizing out large chunks of code that are no longer doing anything meaningful.   Your code looks strange to me anyway.  Your kernel ends with the only output being written to shared memory?  It's not clear to me what you're asking here.   You want someone to explain the reason why commenting out a line of code makes a big change?

Comment: Please post a minimal reproducible. The posted code is incomplete and has a significant number of variables for which you have not specified a size or value.

Comment: Thanks for replying. The code is very big so I am not sure what a minimal reproducible should include. The shared memory write is not the last thing in my kernel but I have commented out all the remaining code to figure out where the kernel is taking up the bulk of time.

Comment: Worth mentioning is that I was too lazy to deal with all the paths and dependencies in VS2008 myself so I just inserted my code in the MatrixMul SDK example that comes with NVIDIA GPU computing SDK 4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The effect you are seeing is the result of compiler optimisation. Taking a compilable version of your basic kernel code:

```
#define H (128)
#define W (128)

__device__
double getElement(const double *g, int t, int j, int w)
{
    return g[t + j*w];
}

__global__ 
void calc_S(double* g_traD, double* LF, double* Ci, double* C)
{
    __shared__ double G[H];

    // Get this block's global index 
    int blockId= blockIdx.x + gridDim.x*blockIdx.y + 
                   gridDim.x*gridDim.y*blockIdx.z;
    int tx= threadIdx.x;
    // This thread's global index
    int gtx= blockId*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    int myTRA[W];
    double my_LF[W];
    for (int i=0; i<W; i++){
        my_LF[i]= LF[gtx];
    }

    for(int j=0; j<W; j++){
        myTRA[j]= getElement(g_traD, tx, j, W);
    }
    double sum;
    for(int j=0; j<W; j++)
    {
        sum += myTRA[j] * my_LF[j];
    }       

    // Write your sum to shared memory
    G[tx]=sum;
    __syncthreads();
}
```

and compiling it with CUDA 5 gives this:

```
$ nvcc -m64 -arch=sm_20 -cubin -Xptxas="-v"  dead_code.cu 
dead_code.cu(13): warning: variable "G" was set but never used

dead_code.cu(13): warning: variable "G" was set but never used

ptxas info    : 0 bytes gmem
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function '_Z6calc_SPdS_S_S_' for 'sm_20'
ptxas info    : Function properties for _Z6calc_SPdS_S_S_
    1536 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 23 registers, 1024 bytes smem, 64 bytes cmem[0]
```

There is a warning about the shared memory variable `G` no being used, but the compiler honors it and emits code consuming 23 registers. So now, if I comment out the `G[tx]=sum` at the end of the kernel, it compiles like this:

```
$ nvcc -m64 -arch=sm_20 -cubin -Xptxas="-v"  dead_code.cu 
dead_code.cu(13): warning: variable "G" was declared but never referenced

dead_code.cu(13): warning: variable "G" was declared but never referenced

ptxas info    : 0 bytes gmem
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function '_Z6calc_SPdS_S_S_' for 'sm_20'
ptxas info    : Function properties for _Z6calc_SPdS_S_S_
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 2 registers, 64 bytes cmem[0]
```

Now there are only two registers used, and the toolchain emitted this:

```
$ cuobjdump -sass dead_code.cubin 

    code for sm_20
        Function : _Z6calc_SPdS_S_S_
    /*0000*/     /*0x00005de428004404*/     MOV R1, c [0x1] [0x100];
    /*0008*/     /*0xfc1fdc03207e0000*/     IMAD.U32.U32 RZ, R1, RZ, RZ;
    /*0010*/     /*0xffffdc0450ee0000*/     BAR.RED.POPC RZ, RZ;
    /*0018*/     /*0x00001de780000000*/     EXIT;
```

ie. four assembly instructions. All your code is gone.

The underlying source of this effect is compiler dead code removal. The compiler is smart enough to determine that code which has no effect on a global or shared memory output is unneeded and can be removed. In this case, one the write to `G` is removed, the whole kernel is effectively pointless, and the compiler just optimises the whole thing away. You can see some other examples of dead code removal and its effects [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14659837/681865) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10494326/681865). The latter is in OpenCL, but the same mechanism applies.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. So please correct me if I'm wrong, this means that the time I am getting when I do the shared memory write is effectively the time it takes my kernel to execute the dot product in full. This actually makes sense because each thread is performing about 544 multiplications and 544 additions, which probably serialize badly. I'll try to do some tiling and see how much improvement I can get. Thanks again :)

Comment: Your understanding is correct. You can see one trick in the first answer I linked to which can be used to defeat the dead code optimisation if you are trying to benchmark individual segments of a kernel.